# How to add the one hidden field while adding or updating or deleting record in Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have tried using event model. that is working fine for adding and updating the record.

But while deleting the existing record in the kendo grid actually it's deleting and adding the hidden field 
 but again that it's showing in the grid when i am clicking to add new record. It should not show in grid but it's should have in dataSource.
 Please anyone help me to achieve this.Thanks.

Here the JsFiddle Link..

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/bagya1985/wftu0vzn/7/][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add filter to dataSource:

```
var savingsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: savings,
    filter: { field: "operationContext", operator: "neq", value: "IsDelete" },
    ...
});
```